# Conversion of null terminated string to Int in Python

Tags: python, c, exception, client, server

I am making a simple python client for a server client architecture. The problem arises when i convert an integer into a string in C and send it over UDP to python client and try to convert it into integer, exception is raised. I thought it might be because of null terminated string in C, so i even tried eliminating the null terminator but no joy. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Python (client) code snippet where i am receiving the information from server.

```
while True:
    try:
        p_ort = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        portnumber =  p_ort[0]

        portnumber.strip()
        #portnumber = portnumber[:-1]
        #portnumber.rstrip("\0")

        #this is where i try to convert the string into integer but the exception is thrown
        try:
            port_number = int(portnumber)
        except:
                print "Exception"

    except:
        print "timeout!"
        break
```

This is my code snippet from server where i am sending the values to client.

```
    void sendDataToClient( int sfd , int index  )
    {

            char portNum[9] = {0};
            sprintf( portNum , "%d" , videos[index].port ); //videos[index].port  is an integer

            if( sendto( sfd , &( portNum ) , 9 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&client , len ) == -1 )
            {
                perror( "sendto()" );
            }

        printf("\nClient Stuff sent!\n");
    }
```

Comment: providing a simple, minimal example would help people help you. In this case, just the data you receive (python side) and the code to interpret it.

Comment: I have edited my code just to the limit where it creates problem.

Comment: `portnumber.strip()` does not change `portnumber`, but `returns` the stripped string.

Comment: @ch3ka, why didn't portnumber.rstrip("\0") work?

Comment: @AliAbbasJaffri because you have not assigned it's return value. `.rstrip` does not modify in place.

Comment: Might be useful if you showed what the exception said.  Also, if you print what's in "p_ort", that might help you figure out what's going on.  And as a general rule in Python, putting large blocks of code in generic "try" "except" catches is very bad form.  Only catch the specific exception type you're looking for and only "try/except" the line of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to strip off the null first.

For example:

```
portnumber = int(portnumber.strip('\x00'))
```

Is how I usually strip off null terminators.  It would be hard to know if this is the correct approach though without seeing a print of portnumber.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! Worked for me!
What i am unable to get is that i have been trying other ways to strip off that null terminator but that didn't seem to work. I tried 'portnumber.rstrip("\0")' but that didn't seem to help at all. Why was that so?

Comment: @AliAbbasJaffri Because in C the null byte \0 is actually the hex value 0x00 which in python is \x00.

Comment: That ought to come handy! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You could also do "chr(0)" for null byte.  Though for a c programmer, maybe not as readable?